# regex expression match parts of an string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match parts of an string into variables after getting the page from curl

the string is

```
value="http://ca.isohunt.com/upload.php?mode=bt&id=880001&sid=3096d80a1c9d2962f8f35a837a3f23e0"
```

I am trying to get `&id=''` and `$sid=''`

i tried using this regex expression using preg_match and it did not work

```
/([^_]*?)&sid-.*?\$
```

Comment: Argh, ignore all the answers that use regex . . . regex is wrong for this.  Use PHP's built in functions, [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) as mentioned in @m.buettner's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/.*?(id=)(\d+).*?(sid=)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $id=$matches[2][0];
      $sid=$matches[4][0];
      print "id = $id <br> sid = $sid\n";
  }
```

Here is the code that you can use to get the 2 values. This gets you the values of the 2 parameters.

Comment: Why use `preg_match_all` when the retrieving code has hardcoded `0`s?

Comment: true you can use preg_match to only get the first occurence

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use regular expressions for this.

If your input string includes `value="` (and the `"` at the end) just extract the URL. You could probably do this easiest using `substr`:

```
$url = substr($input, 7, -1);
```

If the string is more variable, and all you know is that the URL is the stuff inside the quotes, use:

```
preg_match('/".*"/', $input, $match);
$url = $match[0];
```

If your `$input` has only the URL, you can of course skip this step completely. Then:

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$params = array();
parse_str($query, $params);

echo $params['mode'];  // bt
echo $params['id']; // 880001
echo $params['sid']; // 3096d80a1c9d2962f8f35a837a3f23e0
```

Comment: For completeness, you could also use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) without the second argument, and you would have variables $mode, $id, and $sid set for you - note that this could clobber existing variables.

Comment: @ernie yeah that last point is why I wanted to hush up that possibility :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_url`

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
$data = parse_url($url);
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Then:

```
 $queryFields = split('[&]', $data['query']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't escape the `$` unless you're expecting it in the "value" string.

Your regex could be `/&?sid=([^&]+)/` and `/&?id=([^&]+)/`, provided that you don't want to do any checking on the url itself. Or combined: `/&?id=([^&]+).*&?sid=([^&]+)/`.

Remember that the values will be exported to `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` when you're calling something like `preg_match('/&?id=([^&]+).*&?sid=([^&]+)/', $value, $matches);`